# Bootstrap 3 typeahead navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am trying to embed a typeahead instance into my navbar. The code looks like follows:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="navbar-brand" href="#">Time Accounting</span>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="cb_users" type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </form>
        [...]
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

and

```
  $('#cb_users').typeahead({
    source: ['item1','item2','item3']
  })
```

All I am left with is a input field that does't have the typeahead capability.

I am using the component from this repository https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: Are there are errors in the Console while the page is loading or when you type something into the input box?

Comment: From what I can see you shouldn't create the typeahead from both html and javascript. Either set the srouce via `data-source` on the input or remove `data-provide` from the input. Also, if possible please put this in a fiddle so answers can be easily tested.

Comment: Tested your code in FF and it's working..

Comment: For me it is not working in FF either. @asprin I don't have any errors poppign up while I load the website.